# AWK:Remove multiple columns and retain the column delimiters

Tags: awk

I'm trying to remove multiple columns from a text file but I'm getting the output with the column delimiters . The test file doesn't have column headers .

Input

```
1:name:address:city:country:dob:d1:d2:d4:d5
2:name:address:city:country:dob:d1:d2:d4:d5
```

I used the awk command to remove address and d1 and d5

```
awk -F : '{$3=$7=$10=""; print$0}'
```

and the output I got is

```
1 name city country dob d2 d4
2 name city country dob d2 d4
```

is it because I replaced the fields with blank or is it anyother way just to retain the columns along with the delimiters.

Comment: Use `BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}`

Comment: what is your expected output? if you use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {$3=$7=$10=""} 1'` you'll still have `:` character for the fields that you emptied... **edit** just saw the title, that is what you want.. in future, I'd suggest to always add the complete expected output to the question as well to avoid mis-understanding like I did here